# Could Malaysia Airlines Flight 370 have sunk without leaving any floating wreckage?

Tags: accidents, airliner, search-and-rescue

With all the searching on the surface of the Indian Ocean for evidence of Flt. 370, I'm wondering if there's any conceivable scenario in which the Boeing 777 could have sunk without producing any floating wreckage.

Is it possible for a 777 or similar model to hit water without leaving a trace of remains on the surface?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a commercial airliner sink to the bottom of the ocean?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/can-a-commercial-airliner-sink-to-the-bottom-of-the-ocean)

Comment: @danny I disagree, that is about a intact water landing and sinking, this is about crashing in the water and not leaving any floating debris

Comment: Note that MH370 _did_ [leave floating wreckage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370#Marine_debris).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, but only under highly unlikely circumstances.  An airplane contains all sorts of materials that float, from fuel to seat cushions to the plastic cups in the galley.  In order to sink without leaving any floating wreckage, *all* of that material would need to be trapped within the airplane while it fills with water.

In order for this to happen, the airplane needs to land intact on the water.  As any number of ditchings indicate, this isn't going to happen -- even US Airways 1549 had the rear of the fuselage tear open on landing.  More often, the engines or wings will tear off, leaving oil and fuel slicks.

Comment: all of which debris will sooner or later (and most likely sooner) become waterlogged and sink. Depending on environmental conditions that may only take minutes. And that includes the oil slicks which, especially in warm water, can dissipate very rapidly.

Comment: @jwenting not all debris: for example a seat cushion / flotation device or an (even partially) inflated lifejacket will float for a *long* time.

Comment: @yankeekilo yes, for quite a while, but not indefinitely. And in rough seas not very long at all. They're also liable in rough seas or harsh sunlight to be damaged to where their floatation properties are compromised.

Comment: *"In order for this to happen, the airplane needs to land intact on the water."* Which would likely leave survivors able to use the slides as rafts, among other things.

Comment: US Airways 1549 landed on calm water. There is no way to land a large jet intact on any significant waves and there are always waves in the middle of an ocean.

Comment: @AdamDavis - assuming they're still alive and conscious. In the case of MH370 there's reason to believe they weren't.

Comment: @JanHudec there are always waves, but define "significant" - the sea can be very calm and in many areas has low, slow rolling waves which would not pose any intrinsic threat

Comment: @JonStory: Slow-rolling does not matter, only height between highest and lowest point does. I don't know at what height it they start to make a problem, but it won't be that much. Because if the plane bounces of the first wave, it will come down too hard and if it hits a wave at one side, it will start to turn and both are likely to break it apart. It will often be survivable, but it will make getting out seriously difficult for some.

Comment: Not slow-rolling, slow + rolling: as opposed to choppy, fast and high. I'm not saying a jet can or should land on waves, just that the sea can sometimes be very calm indeed. You said that a jet can't land on "significant" waves and that there are "always" waves in the ocean, but there are not **always** "significant" waves

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's certainly possible. But it all depends on a lot of factors.

- Speed of impact. Obviously, the lower the speed of impact the fewer pieces will break away.
- time. Even if things break away and float, after a while they'll sink as they become water logged. And that may only take minutes.
- environmental conditions. Water temperature affects the speed at which chemical spills dissipate. So do wind and currents. Wind and currents, through wave action, can also break up into tiny fragments and cause to sink any floating debris.

So even if something were left on the surface after the impact, after a few hours most of it would be gone. After days, unless the aircraft crashed near a shore and pieces wash up, most likely there's nothing left to see unless very large pieces broke off and managed to stay afloat (which would require very calm surface conditions indeed).

Comment: Not everything that becomes waterlogged sinks. Consider something like a foam seat cushion: if the material the foam is made from is less dense than water, it will continue to float even if the air bubbles become full of water.

Comment: @DavidRicherby until its deteriorated by wave action, salt corrosion, and sunlight to the point where it breaks up.

Comment: Sure but that takes much more than a few hours. Many synthetic materials take years to biodegrade, even in relatively hostile environments. Plastics, for example, don't care if you cover them in salt. If the plane broke up when it hit the water, parts of it will remain afloat for a very long time; the problem is that the parts will disperse over a huge area.

Answer (score 1):

It may possible like the US Airways Flight 1549 ditched in the Hudson River

[image]

This was in a river with smooth water. I'm not sure if there's ever been a passenger jet successfully land intact on the sea.

If the Malaysian flight successfully ditched like Flight 1549, then I'm not sure if the plane could float for hours. It would sink for sure if the doors were opened.

Comment: I'm no expert but Airbus and Boeing have fairly different philosophies when it comes to automation. The Hudson River Landing was due to a combination of piloting skill and an autopilot system that was engaged right till impact and kept the plane in a controlled descent within a safe flight envelope. Boeing gives far more control to the pilots and the autopilot plays a smaller role, which may make the same scenario much less likely with a Boeing. Water landings are not a big part of pilot training as there just isn't enough data to simulate the scenario sufficiently, to the best of my knowledge

Comment: @AsheeshR Whether it is a Boeing or an Airbus, both could have the autopilot engaged in much the same manner for the flight that you refer to.  In fact, even a Cessna with no autopilot, or an Airbus/Boeing with the autopilot disengaged (or even failed) can be flown by the pilot in a similar manner. It is the **pilot's** responsibility to keep the aircraft within a safe flight envelope, **regardless** of what the automation does!

Comment: @Tasos Airliners have to be certified to float. See [Why would an airplane be approved for ditching?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/819)

Comment: @AsheeshR: it doesn't matter about the chances so much, rather the _possibility_ of doing so -- it isn't impossible, nor are the chances extremely remote in calm conditions (storms are another story).

Comment: @Lnafziger I didn't say it isn't the pilot's job; just that the workload is supposed to be decreased by automation, which in turn allows more focus to be put on the problem at  hand.

Comment: Jack lemon Film "Airport '77" :)

Comment: @AsheeshR Well, the autopilot in a Boeing can be used to reduce the workload as well.  :)

Comment: @AsheeshR Your comment prompted a question: [How, exactly, did US1549 land on the Hudson?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2685)