# What is the standard protocol for landing on the ocean?

Tags: emergency-procedures, ditching

If a plane had problems whilst flying and had to land in the ocean, what is standard protocol for pilots and cabin crew to follow in order to try and keep everyone safe?

Comment: For pilots: [Are airliners' pilots trained to safely ditch an aircraft?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/17627/1696)

Comment: You might want to check the [ditching](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ditching) questions we already have, especially [this one](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2994/62) and [this one](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2685/62).

Comment: The first step to safe flying is don't ditch.

Comment: This appears to be a dupe of those two other questions.